# Where to declare variables and functions used in all activities of an app (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm developping my first Android app in Kotlin with several activities. Some of the functions and variables should be accessible from all the activities.

I've defined a data class `Event` and created an instance `eventarray`:

```
 data class Event(
    var name: String?,
    var last_date: Array<String?>,
    var next_date: String?,
    var recurence: Int,
    var Nr_instances: Int
)

var eventarray = ArrayList<Event>()
```

I want `eventarray` to be visible and to be able to modify it in all activities.

Up to now I used two solutions: the first is to use a separate kotlin file `Globaldata.kt` (in the java folder of my android studio project) in which I put this declarations. This works somehow, but I wonder if it is an efficient solution.

The second solution I tried is to define these variables and data class in a separate class BaseActivity and to extend (:) the other activity from this one:

```
 class MainActivity: BaseActivity()
```

This is somehow cleaner (I use the BaseActivity for several things including the language), but it only works as long as I do not have to extend the activities from another activity. For example, I have defined a ListAdapter class which extends from `ArrayAdapter<Event>`

```
class MyEventListAdapter(private val context: Activity, private val eventarray: ArrayList<Event>) : ArrayAdapter<Event>(context, R.layout.eventlistlayout, eventarray)
```

and uses the data class `Event`. In this second solution, I can not extend from the `BaseActivity` class. Therefore, the data class `Event` is not visible in `MyEventListAdpater`.

I have the same problem with functions (`fun`) which are defined in `BaseActivity`. I would like to use them in `MyEventListAdpater`, but they are not visible...

What would you suggest? Should I use my first solution? Or do you have a better one?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a kotlin file and name it "ext" or something and add this to the file:

```
object ext {
    val eventArray : ArrayList<Event> = arrayListOf()
}

data class Event(
    var name: String?,
    var last_date: Array<String?>,
    var next_date: String?,
    var recurrence: Int,
    var Nr_instances: Int
)
```

Then you can add or remove elements like so:

```
ext.eventArray.add(myEvent)
```

Comment: Thanks. Where would you define the `Event` data class in this case?

Comment: you can do it in the same file like the answer I gave. I just edited it. If it helps you. please accept the answer.

Comment: @ Mehran: Hi, thanks. This works fine, but it seems to be the same approach as my first solution using an additional Kotlin file. Na idea with my second solution. Sorry.

Comment: I apologize I just saw that you already had the same approach. Feel free to unmark the answer if you feel it's necessary. However, as for your concern, as long as you clear the array and repopulate it at the correct times, I don't see why this wouldn't be an efficient approach.